# Como abrir dois popup um de cada vez quando atualizar a aba?

Tags: javascript

Pretendo usar dois anúncios popup em meu site, como faço para abrir um de cada vez quando atualizar a página, eu tentei, mas abre dois pop-ups no mesmo tempo irritando qualquer visitante, eu tentei o seguinte script.

```
(function () {
var isOpened = false;

var siteUrl  = "http://popup1";
var siteUrl  = "http://popup2";

document.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (!isOpened) {
        isOpened = !!window.open(siteUrl, "_blank");
    }
  });
})();
```

Comment: @MárcioEric, faça apenas comentarios que tentem resolver o problema da questão.

Answer (score 0):

Desculpe o comentário, mas utilizando `setInterval`, uma variável auxiliar e um método é simples. Segue um exemplo:

```
var openedAds = 0;
var AdsToOpen = ['http://popup1','http://popup1'];
var interval;

var interval = setInterval(function(){
    window.open(AdsToOpen[openedAds], "_blank");
    openedAds += 1;
    if(openedAds === AdsToOpen.length){
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 2000);
```

**AdsToOpen** são os site que você pretende abrir.
**2000** no fim do código é o tempo entre um popup e outro(em ms)

Comment: Esse método que vc me passou abre os dois da mesma forma, eu quero algo que abra o primeiro popup apenas uma vez, depois quando atualizar a aba abrir o segundo popup tudo individualmente.

Comment: Dessa forma, poderia utilizar cookies, porém por que não sortir o ad? tipo, tem 50% de chance de abrir um ad ou aquele outro, assim fica sortido o ad que vai abrir.